# Removing Folders from Linux Tree View?

Tags: tree

**Question:** Is there a way to remove the display of certain folders from the linux `tree` command?

In my case, I'd like to be able to run something like

```
$ tree . --remove-dir=pictures
```

which will remove all directories entitled "pictures" from the tree view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man tree:

```
   -I pattern
          Do not list those files that match the wild-card pattern.
```